# High ping time to router causing lag (Wireshark files included)

Tags: networking, router, ping, wireshark

I'm trying to get my WIFI stable, but it seems like the ping to the router fluctuates from time to time.

Sometimes i get <3ms for hours, other times i have unstable ms from 20 to 1500ms.

Ive uploaded some wireshark files for you guys to analyse. 2 with lag, 1 without.

Can u guys see something wrong here?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6j75u6w4l4xvvz/lag1.pcapng?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzzr2827sqwh7wh/lag.pcapng?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vxrcpvdeap4ldr/nolag.pcapng?dl=0

UPDATE:
Ive uploaded a log when i was playing a game of Heroes of the Storm and had lag spikes every 5 seconds.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5yhfwkqdw63xpd/during%20game.pcapng?dl=0

Comment: Normally external interference like a microwave, or other routers. Try changing the routers channel.

Comment: That is the nature of wireless. It's probably interference. You should use 5Ghz if you can. Or you need to upgrade firmware or drivers. Or you just have two wireless devices not completely compatible with each other. The 2.4Ghz band is saturated. If you live in any moderately populated area it will never be completely reliable.

Comment: I am using the 5Ghz network. I had it stable for about 3 months but now it looks like something changed then.